# Why has the pallet_randomness_collective_flip been removed in polkadot-v0.9.39?

Tags: polkadot, pallet, frame

I noticed that the pallet_randomness_collective_flip has been removed in polkadot-v0.9.39, why is this?

What are the alternatives?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you require randomness in contract execution or within a pallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was renamed to `pallet-insecure-randomness-collective-flip` in [substrate#13301](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13301) to clarify that it is not secure. There were indications that developers used this in production to generate random numbers for security relevant decisions.

The pallet was never intended for that, so we felt prompted to communicate this in a breaking way (by renaming the crate). As of today, there are no secure alternatives that i know of.